# OpenSSH ProxyCommand equivalent in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

I have config file which looks like that

```
Host <NAMEOFHOST>
   user <USERNAME>
   hostname <IP>

Host <NAMEOFHOST2>
   user <USERNAME>
   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p <NAMEOFHOST>
```

and after adding this lines to config file I will be able to connect to server with command

```
ssh <NAMEOFHOST2>
```

However, there is a little problem. I don't have Ubuntu and I'd really like not to install it (because UEFI).

Thus, I'm trying to connect to server with PuTTY.

That's what I've done

```
Connection -> Proxy -> Proxy type = Local
                       Proxy hostname = <NAMEOFHOST>
                       Telnet command = ssh -q -W %h:%p <USERNAME>@<NAMEOFHOST>
Session -> Hostname <NAMEOFHOST2>
           Connection type = SSH
```

When I'm trying to connect to server I get

> Server unexpectedly closed network connection

What's wrong with my settings? Thank you.

---

Update: Thank you for your advise with PuTTY. I tried it, however it didn't want to connect.

Thus, I tried to use OpenSSH. There I just added parameters to `ssh_config`. However, now, when I try to connect to server I get this

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host.

And I don't have any idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 13):

You probably don't have the `ssh` binary on your Windows system.

You can use the [`plink.exe`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) with the [`-nc` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-ncmode) instead of the `ssh` with the `-W` switch:

[image: PuTTY local proxy]

---

An alternative is to open a tunnel via the "NAMEOFHOST" first using an another instance of PuTTY (or Plink).

See for example, *my* guide for [tunneling SFTP/SCP session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty). It's for WinSCP, but just use PuTTY instead of WinSCP in section [Connecting through the tunnel](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty_connecting).

---

Alternatively, you can get `ssh.exe` from [Microsoft build of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH). On Windows 10 version 1803 or newer, OpenSSH is built-in. On older versions of Windows 10, you can install it or you can just download a ZIP package. The client tools do not need any installation, you can just extract them.

See also [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want **ssh** to `172.16.0.21` via `8.8.8.8`

login name in both hosts is `john`

path to private key is `C:\users\john\.ssh\private.ppk`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2splO.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

### .

```
plink.exe -v -ssh %user@%proxyhost -P %proxyport -nc %host:%port   -i "c:\Users\john\.ssh\private.ppk"
```