# Does OpenSSH support multihop login?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, ansible

Ansible uses OpenSSH as the bottomed network communicative implementation, but does it support multi-hop login?

I mean, if Ansible can login a server directly, but can it log in server_a then from server_a login server_b for config the server_b?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not know how Ansible uses OpenSSH.

---

But OpenSSH itself supports *"multihop logins"*.

Since OpenSSH 7.3, you can use [`-J` (jump) switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J) like:

```
ssh -J user1@host1.example.com user2@host2.example.com
```

The `-J` is an equivalent of [`ProxyJump` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump):

```
ssh -o ProxyJump=user1@host1.example.com user2@host2.example.com
```

Note that with file transfer tools, like `scp` and `sftp`, the `-J` switch is supported since 8.0 only. With older versions (but at least 7.3), use `ProxyJump`. See [How can I download a file from a host I can only SSH to through another host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537319/119732#537328)

Also note that the versions refer to local versions of OpenSSH. A remote version of OpenSSH is not relevant.

---

*As @GordonDavisson commented,* with older versions (but at least 5.4), you can use [`ProxyCommand` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand) and [`-W` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#W):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p user1@host1.example.com" user2@host2.example.com
```

---

With even older versions, you can [use `nc` command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Old:_ProxyCommand_with_Netcat) instead of the `-W`:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh user2@%h nc host2.example.com 22" \
    -o HostKeyAlias=host2.example.com \
    host1.example.com
```

---

All the above options are covered in more details in Wikibooks article
[OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies and Jump Hosts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts).

---

Another options is to use port forwarding ([`-L` switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#L)). But that involves two `ssh` instances. I'm not sure if that's possible with Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

For older Ansible versions you had to do it in the general SSH config as described in Martin Prikryls answer. New versions have Ansible specific config as described in the [general FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to)

> **How do I configure a jump host to access servers that I have no direct**
>   **access to?**
>
> You can set a ProxyCommand in the ansible_ssh_common_args inventory
>   variable. Any arguments specified in this variable are added to the
>   sftp/scp/ssh command line when connecting to the relevant host(s).
>   Consider the following inventory group:
>
> `[gatewayed]
>   foo ansible_host=192.0.2.1
>   bar ansible_host=192.0.2.2`
>
> You can create group_vars/gatewayed.yml with the following contents:
>
> `ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@gateway.example.com"'`
>
> Ansible will append these arguments to the command line when trying to
>   connect to any hosts in the group gatewayed. (These arguments are used
>   in addition to any ssh_args from ansible.cfg, so you do not need to
>   repeat global ControlPersist settings in ansible_ssh_common_args.)
>
> Note that ssh -W is available only with OpenSSH 5.4 or later. With
>   older versions, it’s necessary to execute nc %h:%p or some equivalent
>   command on the bastion host.
>
> With earlier versions of Ansible, it was necessary to configure a
>   suitable ProxyCommand for one or more hosts in ~/.ssh/config, or
>   globally by setting ssh_args in ansible.cfg.

This way you have a very Ansible-esque way of setting up SSH bastion hosts only where needed, together with any other special SSH settings (like keys, users, etc).